# Bitbucket server rest api retrieving commit data from a tag that contains slashes

Tags: rest, bitbucket-server, bitbucket-api

I am trying to retrieve commit data for a tag that has slashes in the name using BitBucket REST API for bitbucket server.

Ex tag:

release/2020-09-23-v3.13.4

I am using the following rest URL for a GET request but getting a 404 error.

https://git.server.com/rest/api/1.0/projects/TEST/repos/test/commits/release/2020-09-23-v3.13.4

Is there a way I can properly format this call to retrieve the commit data for the tag above?

Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](https://docs.atlassian.com/bitbucket-server/rest/7.6.0/bitbucket-rest.html#idp380) this one should work

```
https://git.server.com/rest/api/1.0/projects/TEST/repos/test/tags/release/2020-09-23-v3.13.4
```